# Problem using UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm currently smashing my head against a brick wall while trying to get my application back to work.

All i want to do is to show an UIActionSheet as soon as a row in my search tableview is being selected. Simple task one might think...it seems not.

When i start the application on the simulator, it SIGABRT's before it even loaded the rootViewController (StackTrace below). I have absolutely no clue where to start digging.

My App's delegate method "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" runs through smoothly, the last breakpoint i can set in my code is this one:

OverviewViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // this it the last breakable line, jumping over it leads to the SIGABRT
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addNewItem:)];
    [[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:addButton];
    [addButton release];
}
```

OverviewViewController is my NavigationControllers rootViewController, both are initialized in the app's delegate method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

AppDelegate.m

```
OverviewViewController *ovController = [[OverviewViewController alloc] init];

(omitting initialization code for ovController)

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ovController];
[ovController release];

NSArray *tabViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, (my other controllers), nil];
[navController release];

[tabController setViewControllers:tabViews];
[window setRootViewController:tabController];
```

The error started popping up after i started implementing a completely different view (SearchControllerView) using standard UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDateSourceDelegate methods. This view is not even loaded on startup, only when a certain button is clicked.

StackTrace:

```
2011-01-08 13:22:21.279 ReleaseDate[5295:207] -[UITableView _saveOpaqueViewState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x502e000
2011-01-08 13:22:21.282 ReleaseDate[5295:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView _saveOpaqueViewState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x502e000'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0118bbe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x012e05c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0118d6fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x010fd366 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x010fcf22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x006745b3 -[UITableViewRowData initWithTableView:] + 285
    6   UIKit                               0x0052eae3 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateRowData] + 84
    7   UIKit                               0x0052a6da -[UITableView numberOfSections] + 39
    8   UIKit                               0x006c25ee -[UITableViewController viewWillAppear:] + 100
    9   ReleaseDate                         0x00003364 -[OverviewViewController viewWillAppear:] + 68
    10  UIKit                               0x00579c9a -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 858
    11  UIKit                               0x00574606 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 266
    12  UIKit                               0x0068ce01 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 226
    13  QuartzCore                          0x01f25451 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
    14  QuartzCore                          0x01f2517c CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
    15  QuartzCore                          0x01f1e37c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
    16  QuartzCore                          0x01f1e0d0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
    17  UIKit                               0x004c019f -[UIApplication _reportAppLaunchFinished] + 39
    18  UIKit                               0x004c0659 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 690
    19  UIKit                               0x004cadb2 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
    20  UIKit                               0x004c3202 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    21  UIKit                               0x004c8732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x0199da36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0116d064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x010cd6f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x010ca983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x010ca240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x010ca161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    28  UIKit                               0x004bffa8 -[UIApplication _run] + 636
    29  UIKit                               0x004cc42e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    30  ReleaseDate                         0x00002ac4 main + 102
    31  ReleaseDate                         0x00002a55 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Can anybody help me getting on the right track? I'm really starting to go crazy on this one...

**UPDATE**

Implementation of cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"] autorelease];
    }

    // set search item information
    WebSearchItem *wsi = [self.searchData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[wsi title]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [wsi descText], [[wsi releaseDate] dateToString:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]]];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];

    return cell;
}
```

Implementation of OverviewViewController.m init methods

```
- (id)init
{
    [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];  
    [[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"ReleaseDate"];    
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    return [self init];
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

OverviewViewController.h

```
@interface OverviewViewController : UITableViewController {
    ...
}
```

SearchViewController.h

```
@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
    ...
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

Comment: Could you share the code that implements your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` UITableViewDataSource delegate method? I'm guessing that you return a wrongly typed object somewhere, of type `UITableView`, which should be something else.

Comment: I (and with me: google) believe `saveOpaqueViewState` is normally called on `UITableViewCell` objects.

Comment: I would guess there is a problem with the initialization of ovController. Could you provide that code as well?

Comment: see updated question for code excerpts. Note: tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath implementation for OverviewViewController and SearchViewController are almost identical (just setting different values on cell text/detailText)

Comment: minor detail: The templates mostly do `self = [super init...]` although I don't think that it would matter a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in the exception:

```
2011-01-08 13:22:21.279 ReleaseDate[5295:207] -[UITableView _saveOpaqueViewState:]:
                        unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x502e000
2011-01-08 13:22:21.282 ReleaseDate[5295:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
                        exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableView
                        _saveOpaqueViewState:]: unrecognized selector sent to
                        instance 0x502e000'
```

This says that some object (namely: a `UITableView` object, allocated at memory address 0x502e000) was sent a message ("selector", i.e. a method was called on it) which it doesn't understand. The message is `_saveOpaqueViewState:`. Googling around you'll find that this selector is normally called on `UITableViewCell` instances.

That would probably mean that you're returning a `UITableView` somewhere, where you should return a `UITableViewCell` instead.

Please have a look (or share) the code you have for

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)ip
{
}
```

And see if the compiler doesn't give some warnings there.

**update** Ok seeing your code we can conclude that this theory does not apply. The other option is that you prematurely release an object, so that the message sent to some `UITableViewCell` (which has vanished) ends up at another object, incidentally a `UITableView`. You could try and set `NSZombiesEnabled`, or, as a first quick fix, put a line in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` like

```
NSLog(@"returning table view cell at addr %p for indexpath %@",cell,indexPath);
```

Then you can compare the address logged there to the address from the stack trace, just as a start.

**update2** yet another theory then: Do the two `UITableViewController` objects have their own `UITableView` objects? I would imagine that having two controllers trying to work on one table view would lead to some inconsistencies.

Comment: compiler does not give any warnings.

Comment: @schaermu: indeed, code seems ok, it must be a retain/release issue then.

Comment: thanks for your advices, sadly i dont get any log entries before SIGABRT (neither on OverviewViewController and SearchViewController). NSZombiesEnabled didn't clarify anything either...

Comment: @schaermu: are you sure you hooked up all outlets correctly? I.e. every UITableViewController having its own UITableView? You could log any addresses of UITableViews and UITableViewCells so you can easily compare them by hand.

Comment: 2011-01-08 14:41:26.724 ReleaseDate[6990:207] address of Overview tableview: 0x503b800
2011-01-08 14:41:26.726 ReleaseDate[6990:207] -[UITableView _saveOpaqueViewState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x503b800

tackling it down... :) thanks for the advices

Comment: HELL YEAH! everything back to working normally :) it was actually the issue you mentioned, the two controllers didn't have their own tableview instances ;) thanks alot mvds!